# Why is my first bot message (via REST API) shown before my first thread message?

Tags: python-3.x, google-hangouts, hangouts-api, google-chat

I am working on a chat bot, that will return a certain piece of information based on the question of the user. The process of obtaining this information will likely take a couple of seconds, and I want to make sure the user is aware of this.

I therefore use the suggestion from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788704/sending-a-please-wait-message-in-google-hangouts-chat), and return the first message via the REST API via a service account.

The second bot message is then via the normal implementation. I am using the template from the [basic bot here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/hangouts-chat-samples/tree/master/python/basic-bot), deployed to Google Cloud App Engine.

Here a snippet of my code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def home_post():
    """Respond to POST requests to this endpoint.
    All requests sent to this endpoint from Hangouts Chat are POST
    requests.
    """

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        "credentials.json", scopes=SCOPES
    )
    http = httplib2.Http()
    chat = discovery.build("chat", "v1", http=credentials.authorize(http))

    event_data = request.get_json()
    thread = event_data["message"]["thread"]

    message = {"text": "Thanks for your question! Let me check :)", "thread": thread}
    chat.spaces().messages().create(
        parent=event_data["space"]["name"], body=message
    ).execute()

    # doing something to find information requested by user

    return json.jsonify({"text": "Here is my answer :)"})
```

Everything is working as expected, except that the first message coming through in chat is placed before the initial bot mention, after the second message comes through (as seen in the recording or screenshot).

Recording: https://www.loom.com/share/c37472b703184965ad9ee649cb9f17bc

[image]

Why is this happening? What can I do to make sure the order stays the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is only the case in rooms. The order of the messages is correct when messaging the bot directly in a DM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your code is being run [onEvent](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/Event)

Thereby, the [event types](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/EventType) are:

- UNSPECIFIED
- MESSAGE
- ADDED_TO_SPACE
- REMOVED_FROM_SPACE
- CARD_CLICKED

In other words:

**Just adding the bot to the chatroom is already an event that will trigger him to send a message - even before the bot was mentioned.**

How to avoid it:

Implement a conditional statement that checks the type of event before sending a message.

Sample:

```py
if event_data['type'] == 'MESSAGE':
    message = {"text": "Thanks for your question! Let me check :)", "thread": thread}
    chat.spaces().messages().create(
        parent=event_data["space"]["name"], body=message
    ).execute()
else:
    return
```

Sample without `chat.spaces().messages().create`:

```py
if event_data['type'] == 'MESSAGE':
    message = "Thanks for your question! Let me check :)"
else:
    return
return json.jsonify({'text': message})
```

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka for your answer. Note that I already added the bot to the room before mentioning it. Nonetheless I edited my code to include your suggested conditional statement to check for the event type. Unfortunately, the first bot message via the REST API is still moving up prior to my message mentioning the bot.

Comment: What if instead creating a meesage you simply return it as response to the event? See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka, however then the bot is only sending one message. Consider my use case again. I want the bot to first send a message that says "please wait for my answer" then does some work to get the answer, and then sends that answer in a second message. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you check the time on your local machine? Just to rule out that there is a desynchronization between you and the script that is triggering the bot to respond.

Comment: hmm, I am not entirely sure I understand why the time on my local machine would have any impact on this. Note that the script is deployed to Google Cloud and all the timestamps from the messages are in UTC timezone.
I think what is interesting is that the message via the REST API is first below the bot mention and then moves up after the second message (see the screen recording I posted above). It's a really weird behavior.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, so I can only imagine that it is due to time settings as e.g. in [this](https://thecellguide.com/how-to-fix-messages-not-appearing-in-order-on-samsung-141) case. Maybe you can test from a different machine to discard this issue?

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka. Same here, can't figure out what's wrong. I ended up deleting the first message, right before sending the second one. This way, the user sees the "please wait" message and then once the script does it's work, the answer, while the first is removed. Also keeps the chat clean. Thanks for all the help anyway.

Comment: This is a good workaround, I am glad you got it to work!